# Formatting Numbers Inside of a String

Tags: python, string-formatting, number-formatting

Currently I'm working with an API of an online game I play to build a tool, and in doing so I've encountered a problem. The API returns JSON files to the user. While working on creating a class that parses these JSON files for me I've realized I'd like to be able to format a number inside of one of them so instead of being "585677088.5" it's "585,677,088". This would be easy enough if the string just contained this number however this string contains a bunch of other text as well.

Here's a block of the text

```
loan:0
unpaidfees:-3510000
total:585677088.5
```

I'm using python to do this.

The only existing code I have in place is:

```
import urllib2

data = urllib2.urlopen("URL")
```

Comment: Where is your existing code?

Comment: Not needed. I'm simply asking how someone would go about formatting the numbers in the block of text when all of the text is in one big string.

Comment: The only code I can include is a urllib2.urlopen() with a sensitive URL, and I'm not including that.

Comment: If you provided code, it would be easier. It is also dependent on the string. Is it in the same format all the time? Maybe you could do a split, format the portion that's a number and then join. Maybe regex is the way to go.

Comment: Parse, replace, repeat. In other words, convert the string to a structure that makes it easy to replace the value of the fields you want at will. Like, I don't know, a dictionary?

Comment: Well as I stated it's a json file retrieved through an API. The format is the same the only thing that will EVER change is the numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
>>> my_str = """loan:0
... unpaidfees:-3510000
... total:585677088.5"""
>>> map(lambda x: (x.split(":")[0], int(float(x.split(":")[-1]))), my_str.split("\n"))
[('loan', 0), ('unpaidfees', -3510000), ('total', 585677088)]
```

Comment: Agreed. Split is the way to go.

Comment: Wrap the `map` call in `dict` to get a dictionary. It's easier to modify the value of a specific field that way (as opposed to iterating through the whole list and checking each tuple individually).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed, thank you.